# Transit visa for Indian passport holder having Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, turkey, transit-visas

I am an Indian passport holder having a Schengen student visa, I have a layover of 22 hours at Istanbul airport on my flight back to Mumbai from Leipzig, Germany.

I want to know if I need a transit visa if I wish to go sightseeing in Istanbul for those 22 hours. If I need one, then is it a different visa for transit or the same as a normal e-visa? Will I be able to travel on my Schengen visa? I am travelling with Turkish airlines.

Comment: Shenzhen is a city in China.  The town in Europe after which the common visa agreement is named is "Schengen".  The pronunciation is different, too.  Further, you must have a student visa from a Schengen country.  Thereis no such thing as a Schengen student visa.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, i would appreciate if you could help me with my query ignoring the spelling mistake & the pronunciation

Comment: unfortunately I do not know anything about Turkish visa rules for Indian citizens.  I suspect that if you search online with "German visa" rather than "Shenzhen visa" you will be more likely to find the information you need.

Comment: You will need a regular C type visa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @Karlson the country of transit is Turkey, not a Schengen country.

Comment: @ronak Beyond the spelling mistakes, you need to specify what visa you have because “student Schengen visa” is ambiguous and the answer you got might be wrong. What does it say on the visa sticker? How long are you studies? If it's more then three months, what you have got isn't a Schengen (“uniform”) visa but a national visa. Not sure if it makes a difference as far as Turkey is concerned but it's entirely different type of visa.

Answer (score 4):

So, yes it would seem you do need a visa if you want to leave the airport even if you have a valid Schengen visa. This is the relevant portion from the link for Indian citizens,

> Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders are required to have
>   visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders
>   with a valid Schengen or OECD member's visa or residence permit may
>   get their single entry e-Visas valid for one month via the website
>   www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

Comment: +1 for the quote but in all likelihood, what the OP has isn't really a Schengen visa but a German long-stay visa. It should still be OK, though, as it's an OECD member's visa. It also means he can get an e-visa (basically a cheap electronic authorisation somewhat akin to the US ESTA) rather than a real visa.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what OECD was but I know a Schengen visa. Another thing learned today.